# Why my mapView does not display mi circle?

Tags: swift

I have a mapView outlet in my iOS project and I added it to my code:

```
var overlay = MKCircle(center: coords, radius: 100)  
self.mapView.add(overlay)
```

and also, to be sure, i added

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    print("aaa")
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1
    return circleRenderer
}
```

But my mapView is displayed but not the circle, why ?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Does your `rendererForOverlay` method get called?

Comment: What is the value of `coords`?